# How to select a component and deselect the others in an angular ng-For?

Tags: angular, frontend

I am developing a quiz application with Angular. My exam-in-progress component consists of a question component and 4 answer components. The user can select only one answer at a time. The behavior I am trying to achieve is when I select an answer, I want to color its background and uncolor the other answers' backgrounds, so unselect them. How would one do that?

answer component

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Answer } from 'src/app/_models/answer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-answer',
  templateUrl: './answer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./answer.component.css']
})
export class AnswerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() answer: Answer
  @Output() onAnswerChosen = new EventEmitter<Answer>();
  isAnswerChosen: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


  onClick() {
    this.chooseAnswer();
    this.changeAnswerColor();
  }

  public chooseAnswer(): void {
    this.onAnswerChosen.emit(this.answer);
  }

  changeAnswerColor() {
    this.isAnswerChosen = !this.isAnswerChosen;
  }
}
```

```html
<div 
    (click)="onClick()" 
    class="container"
    [ngStyle] = "{
        'backgroundColor': isAnswerChosen ? 'red' : 'green'
    }"
>
    <h4 *ngIf="answer">{{answer.id}} - {{answer.text}}</h4>
</div>
```

exam-in-progress component

```js
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Answer } from 'src/app/_models/answer';
import { IndividualSession } from 'src/app/_models/individual-session';
import { Question } from 'src/app/_models/question';
import { User } from 'src/app/_models/user';
import { AccountService } from 'src/app/_services/account.service';
import { AnswersService } from 'src/app/_services/answers.service';
import { IndividualSessionService } from 'src/app/_services/individual-session.service';
import { NavbarService } from 'src/app/_services/navbar.service';
import { QuestionsService } from 'src/app/_services/questions.service';
import { UsersService } from 'src/app/_services/users.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-exam-in-progress',
  templateUrl: './exam-in-progress.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./exam-in-progress.component.css']
})

export class ExamInProgressComponent implements OnInit {
  individualSession: IndividualSession;
  user: User;
  currentUser$: Observable<User>;
  questions: Question[];
  currentQuestion: Question;
  answers: Answer[];
  currentAnswers: Answer[];
  chosenAnswer: Answer;

  constructor(public navService: NavbarService, 
    public individualSessionService: IndividualSessionService,
    public userService: UsersService,
    public accountService: AccountService,
    private questionService: QuestionsService,
    private answerService: AnswersService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.navService.hide();

    this.startNewSession();
  }

  private startNewSession() {
    this.getCurrentUserData();

    if (localStorage.getItem('currentIndividualSession') === null) {
      this.individualSession = <IndividualSession>{
        ability: 0.5,
        standardError: 1,
        startTime: formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss', 'en-us'),
        examineeId: 1,
        sessionId: 1
      };

      localStorage.setItem('currentIndividualSession', JSON.stringify(this.individualSession));
    }

    let json = localStorage.getItem('currentIndividualSession');
    this.individualSession = JSON.parse(json);
    this.loadData();
  }

  //=========================================================== events

  onNextClick() {
    this.currentQuestion = this.questions[1];
    this.currentAnswers = this.answers.filter(answer => answer.questionId === 3);
    this.shuffle(this.currentAnswers);

    if(this.isChosenAnswerCorrect()) {
      console.log('correct');
    } else {
      console.log('incorrect');
    }
  }

  //===========================================================

  private getCurrentUserData() {
    this.currentUser$ = this.accountService.currentUser$;
    this.currentUser$.subscribe(currUser => {
      if(!!currUser) {
        this.loadUser(currUser.email);
      }
    })
  }



  loadUser(email: string) {
    this.userService.getUser(email).subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
    })
  }

  loadData() {
    this.questionService.getQuestionsFromQuestionnaire(1).subscribe(questions => {
      this.questions = questions;
      this.currentQuestion = questions[0];
      this.loadAnswers();
    });
  }

  loadAnswers() {
    this.answerService.getAnswers().subscribe(answers => {
      this.answers = answers;
      this.currentAnswers = this.answers.filter(answer => answer.questionId === this.currentQuestion.id);
      this.shuffle(this.currentAnswers);
    });
  }

  shuffle(array: Answer[]) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue: Answer, randomIndex: number;
  
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
  
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;
  
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
  
    return array;
  }

  getChosenAnswerData(answer: Answer) {
    this.chosenAnswer = answer;
  }

  isChosenAnswerCorrect() {
    return this.chosenAnswer.isCorrect;
  }


}
```

```html
<p *ngIf="user && currentUser$ | async">{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</p>
<app-question [question]="currentQuestion"></app-question>
<div class="answers">
    <app-answer (onAnswerChosen)="getChosenAnswerData($event)" *ngFor="let answer of currentAnswers" [answer]="answer"></app-answer>
</div>
<app-timer></app-timer>
<button type="button" (click)="onNextClick()">next</button>
```

Comment: Please provide minimal code and try to post what you tried till now for better understanding of your question..

Comment: Sorry, just did that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add styling in parent component class rather than in child.

Try to add `id` for **Answer** class and you can compare with help of it, which will make life easier.

```
<div class="answers">
    <app-answer [ngStyle] = "{'backgroundColor': isAnswerChosen.id == answer.id ? 'red' : 'green'
    }" (onAnswerChosen)="getChosenAnswerData($event)" *ngFor="let answer of currentAnswers" [answer]="answer"></app-answer>
</div>
```

Don't forget to instantiate your isAnswerChosen object in Template.

```
chosenAnswer: Answer = new Answer();
```

or

```
chosenAnswer = {} as Answer;  // or if it's interface
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to change the color and I don't understand why. Also, I think you meant chosenAnswer.id == answer.id. Is it right to put ngStyle there?

Comment: Okay, just put answer components inside a div and applied ngStyle to it and now it works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

create a class -

```
 .red { background-color:red;}
```

create reference variable for all 4 answer conponents and in click function send all 4 reference variable and fifth variable will be the current clicked element-

```
<answer1 #ans1 (click)="changeBackgroundColor(ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4, ans1)"></answer1>
<answer2 #ans2 (click)="changeBackgroundColor(ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4, ans2)"></answer2>
<answer3 #ans3 (click)="changeBackgroundColor(ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4, ans3)"></answer3>
<answer4 #ans4 (click)="changeBackgroundColor(ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4, ans4)"></answer4>
```

in click function first remove class red from all 4 answer component and then apply on selected one

```
changeBackgroundColor(ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4, clicked) {
  ans1.classList.remove('red');
  ans2.classList.remove('red');
  ans3.classList.remove('red');
  ans4.classList.remove('red');

  clicked.classList.add('red');
}
```